# How to delete all files but one in a Windows folder

Tags: windows-7, file-management

In Windows 7 is there a way to select a file and delete all but that file in a folder? Or is there an app for that behavior already in existence? Maybe a right click menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the file you want to keep and then select **Edit > Invert Selection**. Then either hit <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to delete them, or right click over the selected items.

Comment: Didn't know that existed :-) combined with shortcuts its just:
ALT,E,I,DEL

Comment: +1 for the almost keyboard only method. Rock on!!!

Comment: @EricJLN While a little clumsy, you can do keyboard-only by pressing CTRL+A to select all, then using the keys to navigate to the file you want to keep, and pressing CTRL+SPACE.

Answer (score 4):

Press CTRL+A to choose all items, then hold CTRL and left-click to deselect individual files.

Comment: And it works with other windows versions.

Comment: I knew that, I was hoping for a 1 click solution, or 1 keyboard shortcut, every second on the computer helps.  This is actually how I do it now.

Comment: This is the best answer. Would you really want a "delete all but this" entry in the context menu? How often are you really performing this action?

Answer (score 1):

For a mouse-free solution, with file selected (arrow keys?), Ctrl-A, Ctrl+Space.

You could script this with Autohotkey:

```
#SingleInstance Force

!d::
send ^a
send ^{Space}
send {Delete}
return
```

Select file, Alt+D.

To select a file in a folder, you can type the filename whilst the folder has focus. Windows will select the file that matches what you have typed up to that point. Then Ctrl+A, Ctrl+Space, Delete. (Or use above script)

Comment: I like it. Granted, it will only work where one has made the script.

Comment: Ty. "Ctrl+A, Ctrl+Space, Delete" is generic. Script just combines that to one key combination